# How to load div only on click and not when page loads?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can any one help me to shout out my problem in scripting page. I'm developing website which displays property. I wanted to know how to block a div from loading when page loads and the content should display and load only on click of a button. Let me explain it below.

```
<button id="loader" onclick="loaddiv(#items)" value="View Content">
```

This loads data from external server using API. It has lots of data and images.

Please help.

Comment: <button id="loader" onclick="loaddiv(#items)" value="View Content">

Comment: <div id="item" > This loads data from external server using API. It has lots of data and images. </div>

Comment: Show the code your button is triggering, explain what it does wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The DIV itself should not have any content when the page loads, so simply a empty div with an ID tag..

Where you have "loaddiv(#items)" ... this is invalid, well the # part anyway... try "loaddiv('#items')" to make it a string in which jquery can then handle.

Once the page has loaded, then you would use jquery with something like get/post.

```
<div id='items'><!-- i'm empty for now --></div>
<button id="loader" onclick="loaddiv('#items')" value="View Content">

<script>
function loaddiv(sID) {
  $.get( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
    $(sID).html( data );

  });
}
</script>
```